# Different result

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client, google-people-api

I'm trying to pull google contacts information (photos, gender and more) and we used [Google People API](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest) to do that.

I use in [createContact](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact) service to search contact by an Email.

I created a client id and client secret, and with the simple code of oAuth2.0, I got a refresh token that my server used to generate credentials.

```
    HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
    JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

    String clientId = "";
    String clientSecret = "";
    String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts";

    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret,
            Arrays.asList(scope))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .setApprovalPrompt("force")
            .build();

    LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8089).build();

    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
```

In that way, I get the refreshToken and save it offline in a secured file.
After that, my application connect to google and get the clientId, ClientToken, and RefreshToken from that file and try to connect -

```
GoogleCredential googleCredential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
            .setTransport(transport)
            .setClientSecrets(googlePeopleKey.getClientId(), googlePeopleKey.getClientSecret())
            .build().setRefreshToken(googlePeopleKey.getRefreshToken());
```

It seems that the result is different per user. When I operate with a refresh code that my user authenticate earlier, I can't get all the information that another user in my company (that authorized by the same way) does. Today,  it flipped, and in another test, I get results that he didn't. Very strange.

I was looking up about limit rate but, it seems that I even not near the limitations.

Do you have any idea why it returns different result for different users? The different result means that sometimes one of the users can see the profile picture but the other one can't.

Thank you!

Comment: Please include the code you are using to authenticate i think i can show you what the problem is.

Comment: @DaImTo I edit my question with the relevant code, Thank you

Comment: authorize("user")   <---- change user to something else.

Comment: @DaImTo, I made some test with this change but it doesn't fix my problem yet, can you explain to me why this is important? do you have another idea to fix it?

Comment: user should denote different users.   it saves the login credentials in a file some place.   So when you start the program again you wont have to login again because it will have the credentials of the user who last logged in.    Which could be the cause of your user issue.   If you are saving them yourself it kind of sounds like you are mixing diffent users refresh tokens.   Or you have double code and the client library is saving them and you are saving them.

Comment: my expence is mostly with the .net client library its very close to the java client library its just been a while since i have used it.   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/oauth2#data_store

Comment: If this was a quota issue you would have a quota error not missing data or one user seeing another users data.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any errors. Basically, I need only 1 refreshToken for my application. I don't require multiple users. It all starts with the feeling that I didn't get all the data I can pull from google people (for some emails I can't get any pictures) and when I created a new refreshToken / used another user - it works, and I do get the full information about the user. But, Today, when we try to run it - the new refreshCode starts not to give the right data and the old one's works.

Comment: You need one refresh token for every user whos data you want to access.   Refresh tokens are user based if you want to access my data you need a refresh token from me if you want to access yours you need a refres token from you.